# Send an automated email only when a SPECIFIC cell value changes in Google Sheets via App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, onchange

Disclaimer: I'm extremely novice. Don't attack me, please.

I'm trying to get an automated email sent when a specific cell value drops below a pre determined value for inventory purposes.

Currently, I have it working but it sends an email *every* time I edit or change the sheet. I have done research on "OnEdit" vs "OnChange" triggers and can't seem to grasp it yet.

Currently, I am here:

```
function SendEmail() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = file.getSheetByName("Inventory");

  if(sheet.getRange(4,4).getValue()<50){   
    MailApp.sendEmail("email@.com" + "," + "email2@.com", "ReOrder Alert",
    "Hi, Email Body!");
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: What is a event object?

Comment: May be getting lost in translation but not sure the answer to your question...

Comment: Documentation says `onEdit(e) runs when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet.`

Comment: What trigger are you using?

Comment: Cooper — I have tried setting up both the OnEdit and OnChange triggers in App Scripts. The issue I’m having is having that trigger automate the email when only one specific cell value is changed, not any.

Comment: Actually you can set up the trigger to function on a range of cell values but they only fire when a use makes a edit to a cell not where the edit is cause by another script or a formula

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but not sure that helps solved the issue here. I currently have (4.4) which from my learning so far is referring to the specific cell. So I don’t understand why an edit (or a change) is triggering the email automation